# Composer download repository in Gitlab as archive

Tags: php, git, composer-php, gitlab

**TL;DR**

I need a way to make composer download my package as an archive so it excludes files and directories I don't want to be included that are on my .gitattributes as `export-ignore`

**Background info**

I have files in my composer package repository that I don't want to be included in projects that use this package (DataFixtures, Tests, CI configuration). I have setup a .gitattributes file which excludes those folders and files with `export-ignore`.

This works fine when downloading the package as a zip manually but it, of course, doesn't when you checkout the code with git.

This is where my problem starts, I have added the repository manually to the composer.json since it is a private gitlab instance. Whenever I run `composer update` it uses GIT to download the code. I probably need a way to either make composer remove the files that are on the .gitattributes or force it to download my repository as an archive.

**composer.json example**

```
"repositories": [
    {
        "url": "git@<my-gitlab-server>:composer-libraries/testproject.git",
        "type": "git"
    }
],
......
"require": {
    "myownvendor/testproject": "^1.0",
}
```

Is there a way to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting the `preferred-install` method for this repository to `dist` in your `composer.json`:

```
{
    "config": {
        "preferred-install": {
            "myownvendor/testproject": "dist"
        }
    }
}
```

Alternatively, install dependencies by running

```
$ composer install --prefer-dist
```

For reference, see:

- https://getcomposer.org/doc/06-config.md#preferred-install
- https://getcomposer.org/doc/03-cli.md#install

Comment: This worked perfectly for me. I also found out that you can add it as a "package" type in the repositories, that way it'll always download it as a distribution zip: https://getcomposer.org/doc/05-repositories.md#package-2